# Import dmp files for starters

Tags: java, batch-file

I am developing a script (dos command line) for QA/Testers. So they would run the script from command line with some arguments and it would import multiple dmp files required for a test scenario.

Can this be accomplished using a batch file or should i use java for much more effective script/tool?

Please suggest.

Comment: yes, it can probably be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about importing some data from a dmp file. It can be achieved using, for example in Oracle imp or impdp. Both can be called with parameters triggered from a batch file. This will require you to have some database tools installed on the QA machine though, which isn't necessarily the case.

Not sure how you would achieve, loading a dmp file, from within Java any easier.